# Roblox Lua trying to tween part to move back and fourth like a platform

Tags: lua, roblox, tween

I've been practicing tweening on Lua and I'm struggling to understand why I can't get my platform to move back and fourth between a start and an end platform. First I'll show the code

```
-- Starting Variables
local TweenService = game:GetService("TweenService")
local group = game.Workspace.MovingPlatform

-- Group Variables
local part = group.Platform
local start = group.Check1
local finish = group.Check2

-- Vectors
local destination = Vector3.new(start.Position.x,start.Position.y, start.Position.z)

-- Platform Tween Info
local info = TweenInfo.new(
    1, --Length (seconds)
    Enum.EasingStyle.Linear,
    Enum.EasingDirection.Out,
    -1,--Times To Be Repeated
    true,
    0 --Delay
)

-- Where the destination is
local Goals = { 
    Position = Vector3.new(destination)
}

-- Makes it go
local MovePart = TweenService:Create(part, info, Goals)
MovePart:Play()

-- Debugging
local startPosition = Vector3.new(start.Position.x, start.Position.y, start.Position.z)
local endPosition = Vector3.new(finish.Position.x, finish.Position.y, finish.Position.z)
local partPosition = Vector3.new(part.Position.x, part.Position.y, part.Position.z)
while true do
    print("Start Position: "..tostring(startPosition))
    print("Destination: "..tostring(destination))
    print("End Position: "..tostring(endPosition))
    print("Platform Position: "..tostring(partPosition))
    print("--------------")
    wait(3)
end
```

The platform will move once and then start bugging out and going anywhere and eventually will rest on the floor moving back and fourth but not at the correct location. I've tried debugging to see if the positioning of any of my parts were somehow changing but everything stayed the same. Maybe I'm not logging the positions correctly but nonetheless any hints at what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try using CFrame instead of Position when moving things.
Also, Part.Position is a Vector3 so there's no point in creating a new Vector3 for a Vector3.

Try something like this:

```lua
-- Starting Variables
local TweenService = game:GetService("TweenService")
local group = game.Workspace.MovingPlatform

-- Group Variables
local part = group.Platform
local start = group.Check1
local finish = group.Check2

-- Set the platform part to start at Check1
part.CFrame = start.CFrame

-- Platform Tween Info
local info = TweenInfo.new(
    1, --Length (seconds)
    Enum.EasingStyle.Linear,
    Enum.EasingDirection.Out,
    -1,--Times To Be Repeated
    true,
    0 --Delay
)

-- Where the destination is
local Goals = { 
    CFrame = finish.CFrame -- We want it to end at the finish part's position
}

-- Makes it go
local MovePart = TweenService:Create(part, info, Goals)
MovePart:Play()
```